# Closed formula for the generating function of the sequence of powers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, generating-functions

Does anyone know of a closed formula for the function
$f_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^k x^n}$ ? That is, the generating function of the sequence $1^k,2^k,3^k...$.

It is not hard to see that $f_k(x)=\frac{P(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$, where $P(x)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $k$ (this follows from the identity $f_k(x)=x\cdot f'_{k-1}(x)$ ). A closed formula for the coefficients of $P(x)$ would be very helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your polynomials are $x$ times the [Eulerian polynomials](http://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_polynomials).

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is the polylog function $\text{Li}_{-k}(x).$